# The Golang Http Server hangs up whenever I test this Rest API via PostMan to test the concurrent process

Tags: concurrency, goroutine, channel

I m trying to test the behavior's of Channels after triggering in a go-routine via Post (Rest API).

The Function that i am facing problem is concurrent2. Not sure what's the issue with the function. The last variable message writes all the data, but somehow it doesn't send the data to the http writer. Maybe channel is blocking the main go-routine.

The code is somewhat like

```
func concurrent2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        chalk := make(chan string)
```

```
        for i:=0; i< 4; i++ {
            go func() {
                log.Print("=>")
                chalk <- "Hello"
            }()
        }
        
        fmt.Println("out Of the Loop")
        var message string
        for value := range chalk {
            message += value
            log.Print("Value 2 ", message)
        }
        
        w.Write([]byte(message))
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4JSn.png)

tried to use waitgroup and close the channel such as:

```
func concurrent2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   chalk := make(chan string)
   var wg sync.WaitGroup
```

```
        for i:=0; i< 4; i++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                log.Print("=>")
                chalk <- "Hello"
            }()
        }

        fmt.Println("out Of the Loop")
        var message string
        for value := range chalk {
            message += value
            log.Print("Value 2 ", message)
        }
        close(chalk)
        wg.Wait()
        
        w.Write([]byte(message))

 }
```

but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The channel was blocking. Just use the buffered channel of the same length as the loop.

```
chalk := make(chan string, 4)
```

Also, the channel should be closed after `wg.wait()`.

Answer (score 0):

The channel you are using is an unbuffered channel. Every time you write data into an unbuffered channel it gets blocked until that data is read by another go routine.
As mentioned in the previous answer, you need to specify a size when creating the channel using `make` function. This way, you create a buffered channel. Unlike unbuffered channels, buffered channels are only blocked when their maximum capacity is reached.

So you need to make your channel like this :

```
//We use 4 as capacity because you only write 4 data into the channel
chalk := make(chan string)
```

For more on buffered channels and unbuffered channles, you can [visit here](https://clavinjune.dev/en/blogs/buffered-vs-unbuffered-channel-in-golang/).